# How can I get global step in tensorflow.estimator?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

Does anyone know, how can I get the global step count in estimator definition?
I need it to adjust the learning rate, when the optimizer created.
like the example below:

```
def estimator_fn(features, labels, mode):
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer=xxx(learning_rate=GLOBAL_STEP*some process)
```

And does `tf.train.get_global_step` work?

Comment: Yes, you can use tf.train.get_global_step function. There is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404564/what-does-tf-train-get-global-step-do-in-tensorflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this:

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
   global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
   learning_rate = learning_rate_fn(global_step)
```

where learning_rate_fn is a function that you can modify your learning rate.

For more info look at [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/57e075203f8fba8d85e6b74f17f63d0a07da233a/official/resnet/resnet_run_loop.py#L367).